# Reading from an updating chatlog.txt until a particular line appears

Tags: python, text-files, readline

I have just recently started coding in python and found myself overwhelmed when it came to creating this script.

So, I have a chatlog.txt file that is constantly being updated and I want to make it so that whenever a new line that contains "Apple" (for example) appears, something happens (ex. print("Green")). Of course, this would be a loop and the exit conditions would be when "Apple" has appeared five times.

> chatlog.txt

```
Adam received a pear
Adam received a pear
Adam received a tomato       # This is the chatlog.txt file when it is first opened
Adam received an orange
Adam received a banana
```

All of the lines when the chatlog.txt file should be ignored and only the ones that come them should be taken into account.

```
A̶d̶a̶m̶ ̶r̶e̶c̶e̶i̶v̶e̶d̶ ̶a̶ ̶p̶e̶a̶r̶
A̶d̶a̶m̶ ̶r̶e̶c̶e̶i̶v̶e̶d̶ ̶a̶ ̶p̶e̶a̶r̶
A̶d̶a̶m̶ ̶r̶e̶c̶e̶i̶v̶e̶d̶ ̶a̶ ̶t̶o̶m̶a̶t̶o̶
A̶d̶a̶m̶ ̶r̶e̶c̶e̶i̶v̶e̶d̶ ̶a̶n̶ ̶o̶r̶a̶n̶g̶e̶
A̶d̶a̶m̶ ̶r̶e̶c̶e̶i̶v̶e̶d̶ ̶a̶ ̶b̶a̶n̶a̶n̶a̶
**Adam received an apple**     -> This triggers Messages()
```

> Messages

````
```python
import pyautogui as sendstuff

def Messages():
    sendstuff.press("enter")
    sendstuff.typewrite("That is a nice apple!")
    sendstuff.press("enter")
```
````

How do I do this?

Comment: Hi! I recommend to include: 1) Your attempt code 2) An example of your txt file 3) And the Errors or misbehaviors that you are finding while executing your code. Please refer to these guidelines [how to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If you follow the guidelines I guarantee that more people will be able to help you, thanks!

Comment: BTW, I don't recommend using an infinite for loop. As it could happen that your condition will never be met. Instead, I'll recommend creating a job in your OS task manager that executes this script with frequency X, in that way if your condition is not met in a period of time fixed by you, the code will finish and retry later.